# what does this macro definition do？

Tags: c++, c

I have no idea what ALIGMENT_ATTRIBUTE(B) is suppose to do in typedef because it is a empty definition. Does it form a function?

```
#define ALIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTE(B)

typedef ALIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTE(8) UInt64   T_AUInt64;
```

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: The macro is part of some multi-target or multi-object build scheme. When other targets or options are selected for the build, the macro is defined with replacement text that provides an alignment attribute. You should have shown more context when posting this question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: As it is a preprocessor macro it can be used for both languages. As nobody looks for preprocessor tag, tagging with C and C++ is quite fine!

Comment: @Klaus: Guidance for the C stand is “it should not be combined with the C++ tag absent a rational reason” and a reason that you want the attention of people who have chosen to follow the C tag but not the C++ tag (or vice versa) is disrespectful tag spam, not a rational reason.

Comment: I agree with @Klaus. This approach of closing the question just because it's tagged under both language, and despite the fact that the actual contents of the question is agnostic (not specific to only one of these languages), is generally harmful. And in this specific case, a pretty good (and totally "legitimate") question got closed for no good reason. IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

It can be used in platforms where the alignment matters.

For example, it can be used in a platforms where `uint64` must be located at an address which is divisible by 8.

In such scenario, you'd need to extend the definition of `ALIGNMENT_ATTRIBUTE(B)` using the platform's alignment-enforcement mechanism (which is typically compiler-specific), such as `#pragma align(8)` or `alignas(8)` or `_declspec(align(8))`.

In your specific example, it is defined as nothing, which implies that your platform does not have any alignment restrictions.

Comment: BTW, all I've written above is based on a hunch (alongside a bit of common sense). I don't know all of this for sure, as I've never encountered such scenario, where you'd want to support platforms that are so fundamentally different from each other. It just seemed like the most reasonable explanation of that empty definition at the top of the question.

Comment: Possibly on some platforms `alignof(UInt64)` is 8 and on some it's 4, which messes with struct padding (or is part of some ABI constraint), so on 32 bit platforms the define is one of these alignment specifiers

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb OMG, thank you so much for the crystal clear explanation. This is piece of code I encountered going through a program that was developed ages ago, 1980s or earlier.

Comment: @jojo_Aero_smith_the_dummy: glad to have helped!